# sparql query: URL as a parameter, using with Python and Sesame-Workbench

Tags: python, rdf, sesame, sparqlwrapper

I am trying to send a URL as a parameter to the sesame workbench, using sparql. How can I do that?

More specifically, A working sample from my code is;

```
p="OSPF"
queryString = ("""
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX FOAF: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://something.com>

INSERT DATA {
: rdf:type FOAF:productdetails ;
FOAF:price :%s .
}""")% p
```

In the output the object for the predicate  *'price'* is *'http://something.com/OSPF'*.  I want *www.myurl.com* as the object.

Comment: As an aside: you shouldn't programmatically send queries to the Sesame _Workbench_. The Workbench is just a client UI. Send your queries to the actual Sesame Server instead.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra How can I do that? What will be the end point then?

Comment: typically something like `http://<server>/openrdf-sesame/repositories/<repositoryId> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no Python programmer, but it looks like you're using string formatting (with the `%` operator) to insert a value into your SPARQL query. In this instance, the value of `p` ("OSPF") is inserted into your string, replacing the `%s`. So the outcome of this is:

```
  FOAF:price :OSPF .
```

The `:` in front of `OSPF` means that you are using a prefixed name here, with the default prefix. The default prefix is defined in your namespace declarations as:

```
  PREFIX : <http://something.com>
```

This leads to the eventual URI inserted in your SPARQL query being:

```
  FOAF:price <http://something.comOSPF> .
```

If you want a different URL, you have to change the way this is substituted. One solution is to have the full URI as the value of `p`. You then need to remove the leading colon from `%s` and instead surround it with angle brackets (to indicate it's a full URI):

```
   p = "http://www.myurl.com/OSPF" 
   queryString = ("""
   PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
   PREFIX FOAF: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
   PREFIX : <http://something.com>

   INSERT DATA {
    : rdf:type FOAF:productdetails ;
      FOAF:price <%s> .
    }""")% p
```

Another option is to introduce another namespace declaration in your SPARQL query, and use that in front of `%s`. For example:

```
   p = "OSPF" 
   queryString = ("""
   PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
   PREFIX FOAF: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
   PREFIX my: <http://www.myurl.com/> 
   PREFIX : <http://something.com>

   INSERT DATA {
    : rdf:type FOAF:productdetails ;
      FOAF:price my:%s .
    }""")% p
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with your first clarification. If there is something missing from your question, can you edit it to include the necessary information?

Comment: Edited: Two clarifications;1. IF I am using <%s> inside the query, the object part of triplet output (when viewing the output of 'SELECT * where { ?a ?b ?c }', with the direct query facility of sesame-work bench) also contains the angle brackets like <www.something.com>. How can I get rid of it? _one more thing is_ if I want to pass a variable containing some special characters(especially spaces), how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds more like a different question really. If you have a new question post it *as a separate new question*. You can provide a link back to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Sure. The link follows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974964/url-special-character-parameter-in-sparql-query-python-sesasmworkbench